# Azure Background Service

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles

We have a background worker role that runs a few services for us. A communication service and a notification service. when i run my code locally both these services run and Im able to write to a log and all seems fine. When I point my config files at production connections strings and other production variables and run my local code against it - it all works as expected. When I push the code to Azure my service doesnt seem to run, I no longer see any data being written to my log table.

We have another solution where we do the same thing (communication and notification service) and this works as expected in this other solution.

I have compared all references in our working solution to those references in our non-working solution - all needed dlls have been set to copyLocal=true - We've tried a variety of different tools to see what the issue is but we have not been able to pin point the exact issue.

EDITED:

1. This is a simple process in the background
2. I write to the log using a built logging utility - this log table exists on our sql azure database
3. We verify that this is working - on account that the service spins up with the azure utility and eventually says 'Ready' - in past occurances - we'd get the error messages or it would just continue to spin.
4. Our service is started up by the WorkerRole.cs file - Run / OnStart.

Comment: Your posting is not clear so I have a few questions. 1) Is this a Windows Service or a simple process works in background? 2) How do you write these log and where this log table existed? 3) When you deploy your application to Windows Azure how do you verify that your worker process is working? 4) Is this process launched using ProgramEntryPoint or from startup task or how do you launch it in Windows Azure?

Comment: Avkash - thanks for your questions - I have added some edits to my initial question - thanks again.

Comment: OK - without seeing code or config, this is sort of a shot in the dark, but how about these:  Database access via the Firewall configured correctly? Everything getting published to Azure (i.e. no missing dependencies?)  You can RDP into the WorkerRole and check the EventLog entries to see if that gives you a clue...

Comment: If you have Visual Studio Ultimate you can try setting up intellitrace to (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jnak/archive/2010/06/07/using-intellitrace-to-debug-windows-azure-cloud-services.aspx) to see if the process is actually working and is just not getting the logs to where you are expecting to see them. If you don't have Intelltriace then you can deploy a debug build with Debug statements at various places and RDP into the machine and use SysInternals DebugView to see the output of those messages.

Comment: This has happened to me as well; it's probably something simple and stupid such as a missing DLL or an assembly that's being loaded from the GAC that is not the version your service expects. Or it's writing the log to the wrong directory, or it doesn't have permission. As MikeWo said, use remote desktop to log on the instance and sniff around. Check the system events as well for errors.